# Adding column to SQL Android

Tags: android, sql

I'm having a problem adding a column to my SQLite table. It shows an error message that the column `local` does not exist. I am approaching in this way for an exam. Can someone help me?

Main Activity:

```
private Cursor obterCidades() {
      String[] projection = {
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry._ID,
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_CIDADE + " AS CIDADE ",
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_LOCAL + " AS LOCAL ",
            LocalizacoesContract.PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.PaisEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_PAIS + " AS PAIS "
    };

    String sortOrder =
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_CIDADE + " ASC";

    c = db.query(
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + " INNER JOIN " +
                    LocalizacoesContract.PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            projection,
            LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS + "=" +
                    LocalizacoesContract.PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." +
                    LocalizacoesContract.PaisEntry._ID,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            sortOrder
    );
    return c;
}
```

Here is the Contract:

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public final class LocalizacoesContract {
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // give it an empty constructor.
    public LocalizacoesContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class CidadeEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cidade";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOME_CIDADE = "nome";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOME_LOCAL = "local";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS = "id_pais";

        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
               "CREATE TABLE " + CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                       CidadeEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                       CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS + " INTEGER, " +
                       CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_CIDADE + TEXT_TYPE +
                       CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_LOCAL + TEXT_TYPE +
                       ", FOREIGN KEY (" + CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS + ") "
                       + "REFERENCES " + PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" + PaisEntry._ID + "));";

        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
               "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    }

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static abstract class PaisEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pais";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NOME_PAIS = "nome";

        public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
               "CREATE TABLE " + PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                       PaisEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                       PaisEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_PAIS + TEXT_TYPE + " )";

        public static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
               "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME;
    }
}
```

It shows me an error saying that column `local` does not exist.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + CidadeEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    CidadeEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS + " INTEGER, " +
                    CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_CIDADE + TEXT_TYPE +
                    CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_NOME_LOCAL + TEXT_TYPE +
                    ", FOREIGN KEY (" + CidadeEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID_PAIS + ") "
                    + "REFERENCES " + PaisEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" + PaisEntry._ID + "));";
```

Go and log what this produces. You will find something in there along the lines of `nome TEXTlocal TEXT` as you forgot to use the comma separators.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was missing a comma between the 2 columns